Поменять путь к вебдрайверу на selenium
По-умолчанию в моем коде не был установлен путь для вебрайвера и вообще его я не скачивал он сам автоматически установился с библиотекой.
Сейчас требуется поменять путь к вебдрайверу и я не понимаю как это сделать, подобный код не работает, пишет ошибку Unexpected argument

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='...')


Вам нужно либо передавать путь до драйвера первым неименованным аргументом.
driver = webdriver.Chrome('path_to_driver', options=options)
Либо использовать класс Service для инициализации:
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


service = Service(executable_path='path_to_driver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)


